# Windows.Web.HttpClient.SendRequestAsync never returns in release mode but works in debug mode c# winrt

Tags: c#, httpclient, uwp

The following statemtent works in debug mode , but when i turn on the optimize code and build in the release mode , it never returns. I am able to see the response through fiddler , but the it is not returning and the application freezes. By the way it is a get request for a file .

```
responsemsg = await httpclient.SendRequestAsync(requestmsg)
          .AsTask(cts.Token,progressCallback).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

The same statement works for other methods like post, propfind etc. But fails for get and put.

Comment: Have you attempted to disable .NET Tool Chain?

Comment: That is necessary to upload to store . So did'nt disable it.

Comment: Have you tried running in Release and AnyCPU

Comment: Nope , I am trying now and I'll let you know.

Comment: The only reason I ask is because I have a UWP app that consumes JSON apis from the web. When I choose a specific build type with release it runs super slow and hangs. It SEEMS it's hanging on the deserialization but there are async http requests going out simultaneously so it's entirely possible it's those.

Comment: It says : Project not selected to build for this solution configuration . Build skipped.

Comment: Right click on your solution and choose configuration manager. Make sure that it's setup to build for the one you have

Comment: Actually i am not having any problem with other deserializations , the only problem is with downloading files using get request. I am able to get and deserialize other json responses . But failing in the download case as mentioned , that too only in release mode.

Comment: It did not work in that case also . I set it to Any CPU and platform to (x64 - my computer.). It failed.

Comment: Well I am out of ideas for now. Sorry. From my understanding .NET Toolchain will slow things down when debugging. So you disable it while you work then enable it before you deploy to market. Hope that helps. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your concern Anthony ! If I figure out something , I'll post it here.

Comment: I am having a simelar issue that I cannot exlpain. When running my code in production. `HttpClient.PostAsync()` doesnt reutrn or timesout

Comment: I wrote an asynchronous task before i used httpclient.sendrequest method  (the call is not in that async task) , but during the optimization , it resulted in a problem , i removed the ascynhronous task and it worked fine. The mentioned asynchronous task had nothing to do with httpclient methods , except conditionally giving a cancellation token , so i removed it and it worked fine